Why does Windows add my program to the Start Menu?
Hi I have an interesting situation. I am working on a Windows program in Visual Studio and for some odd reason Windows added a shortcut to the program in AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs.
The link points to the executable in the Visual Studio build directory. Any idea why Windows is doing this? I run the executable very frequently so I'm guessing Windows decided to create the shortcut automatically.
Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Windows isn't doing this. Visual Studio on the other hand, might. What type of application are we talking about, is it perhaps a UWP app?

Nope just a standard Windows app made in C++. I observed the same behavior on another computer however. This was a customer's computer and there were the usual links in the start menu that my installer created. However there was also a link similar to my computer in the start menu, not in any folder, that pointed to the exe in the program files subfolder. My installer did not create these shortcuts.

Can you look through and/or show the build settings? What specific process that you initiate creates the shortcut?

May be you use a library in that program that creates a link to itself on it's own?

I looked a little deeper, this has nothing to do with the installer or Visual Studio. The customer's computer generates the same shortcut so Visual Studio cannot be causing it. Also I tried deleting the shortcut and found it was recreated every time I launched the executable, whether within or outside of Visual Studio. Any ideas? I might have to peruse through my code to see where the culprit lies.

Also I am using the Qt framework so maybe some class I use has this side effect.

Found it ... I am using WinToast https://github.com/mohabouje/WinToast and it is the culprit. That was easy :)

@riverofwind you have to answer your own question then :)

Turns out it wasn't Windows, it was the WinToast library. To raise toast notifications in Windows you have to have a special shortcut to the program you're running that has a property set on it containing the Application User Model ID. Thus the library defaults to creating a shortcut with this property to make toast notifications possible.
